# Error: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels, arima

So I have a CSV file with two columns: date and price, but when I tried to use ARIMA on that time series I encountered this error:

> ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated
> frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
> ' ignored when e.g. forecasting.', ValueWarning)

So I found these two questions:

[ValueWarning: No frequency information was provided, so inferred frequency MS will be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547245/valuewarning-no-frequency-information-was-provided-so-inferred-frequency-ms-wi)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35860703

But when I tried to run the code in the example ( the 2nd link ) :

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA

df=pd.DataFrame({"val": pd.Series([1.1,1.7,8.4 ], 
                 index=['2015-01-15 12:10:23','2015-02-15 12:10:23','2015-03-15 12:10:23'])})
print df
'''
                     val
2015-01-15 12:10:23  1.1
2015-02-15 12:10:23  1.7
2015-03-15 12:10:23  8.4
'''

print df.index

'''
Index([u'2015-01-15 12:10:23',u'2015-02-15 12:10:23',u'2015-03-15 12:10:23'], dtype='object')

'''

df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
print df.index
'''
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-15 12:10:23', '2015-02-15 12:10:23',
               '2015-03-15 12:10:23'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
'''

model = ARMA(df["val"], (1,0))
print model
```

I also received the same ValueWarning, so I tried to change this line:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

to this:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index.values, freq=df.index.inferred_freq)
```

But then I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'

Comment: Is your data monthly? If so, you can do `df.index = df.index.to_period('M')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang it says that this method doesn't exists, I just did: `print(type(df.index))` and this was the output: `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>` hopefully this information will help

Comment: `type(df.index)` doesn't really help :-). Next time try `df.index.dtype`. Anyway, you should only do `to_period('M')` on `DatetimeIndex` so `df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).to_period('M')`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You current index, as printed, is string index. You should convert it to `DatetimeIndex` and pass a frequency by `to_period`:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).to_period('M')
```

Comment: But I'm seeing dtype='datetime64[ns]' from the OP's second output of `df.index`. How come you say the indices are strings?

Comment: @Saeed that sentence is actually for the second part, when OP changes from `df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)` to `pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index.values, freq=...)`. At that point, `freq=df.index...` is not valid because of the incorrect type.

Answer (score 2):

If your time series is irregular, you might end up receiving an error like this.

> "ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not
> conform to passed frequency M"

Depending on what you want to do with you data, you could try different things.
What worked for me was [pandas resampling, better explained here.](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-the-pandas-resample-function-a231144194c4)