# SARIMAX error:ValueWarning:A date index has been provided,but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I have data like this

| Time | Humidity_(%) |
| --- | --- |
| 15:21:02 | 31.03 |
| 15:23:05 | 30.98 |

when i run the code i got this error :
ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
Any one familiar with this can help me?
I do not know what is the cause

i wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm


data.set_index('Time', inplace=True)


# Split the data into train and test sets
train_data = data.iloc[:-17000]  # Use all but the last 8 samples for training
test_data = data.iloc[-17000:]   # Use the last 8 samples for testing

# Fit a SARIMAX model to the training data
model = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(train_data['Humidity_(%)'], order=(1, 0, 0))
model_fit = model.fit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510659/error-valuewarning-a-date-index-has-been-provided-but-it-has-no-associated-fr)